# Login with twitter to get user profile asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I have a web application in asp.net . I want to use login with twiiter to get get user info. I have followed all instructions mentioned in below article

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Login-with-Twitter-in-ASPNet-using-Twitter-Button.aspx

I am getting redirected to twitter app then after authentication I am being redirected to my localhost app. Then I have check user is authorized but when I try to get user details by method **FetchProfile()** I am getting error.

My code is as below :

First on button click

```
protected void LoginTwitter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!TwitterConnect.IsAuthorized)
    {
        TwitterConnect twitter = new TwitterConnect();
        twitter.Authorize(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);
    }

}
```

then after authenticating back from twitter . on page load of application
I have check url its

```
http://localhost:63977/Account/Login?oauth_token=K0mECAAAAAAAxRXEAAABV44xPgc&oauth_verifier=qYLFiOlFPx4gxEu6V4AmTJG2JNjJ3nV2
```

then code to check

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TwitterConnect.API_Key = HelperClasses.TwitterApiKey;
    TwitterConnect.API_Secret = HelperClasses.TwitterApiSecret;

    if (Request.QueryString["oauth_token"] != null)
    {
        //twiiter
        if (TwitterConnect.IsAuthorized)
        {
            TwitterConnect twitter = new TwitterConnect();
            //LoggedIn User Twitter Profile Details
            DataTable twitterUserDataTable = twitter.FetchProfile(); // error here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tweetinvi provides a sample project doing exactly what you want to do : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/tree/master/Examplinvi.Web.

I have highlighted the lines you will be interested in :

https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/master/Examplinvi.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L14-L36

You can also find more about the Authentication in tweetinvi here : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Authentication.

Here is the snippet that you want to use of ASP.NET authentication :

```
private IAuthenticationContext _authenticationContext;

// Step 1 : Redirect user to go on Twitter.com to authenticate
public ActionResult TwitterAuth()
{
    var appCreds = new ConsumerCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET");

    // Specify the url you want the user to be redirected to
    var redirectURL = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/Home/ValidateTwitterAuth";
    _authenticationContext = AuthFlow.InitAuthentication(appCreds, redirectURL);

    return new RedirectResult(authenticationContext.AuthorizationURL);
}

public ActionResult ValidateTwitterAuth()
{
    // Get some information back from the URL
    var verifierCode = Request.Params.Get("oauth_verifier");

    // Create the user credentials
    var userCreds = AuthFlow.CreateCredentialsFromVerifierCode(verifierCode, _authenticationContext);

    // Do whatever you want with the user now!
    ViewBag.User = Tweetinvi.User.GetAuthenticatedUser(userCreds);
    return View();
}
```